# Access non es6 npm module functions within JSX file

Tags: reactjs, import, ecmascript-6, jsx

I want to use a module that I recently npm installed. I want to use it from within a jsx file but I don't know how to 'import' it if you will. There are no examples doing this in the documentation for this module and I assume it is just common knowledge on how to use it - knowledge I can't find / don't have.

I don't think this module has any 'exports'. It just has a dist folder with the .js source code inside of it.

How do I access this module's functions from within my jsx file? Do I need to `import` it some how?

Comment: How does the library export its code? Does it create functions on the global `window` object? Or better yet - what is the module that you are trying to use?

Comment: @grammar the module in question is rangeslider.js and I am honestly unsure how it exports its code, I am somewhat nooby and am trying to figure all this out, sorry!

Comment: That's OK :) Just trying to get as much info as possible to help you out. Check out Chase's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage docs for [`rangeslider.js`](http://rangeslider.js.org/) contain a code example:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="rangeslider.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // Initialize a new plugin instance for all
    // e.g. $('input[type="range"]') elements.
    $('input[type="range"]').rangeslider();

    // Destroy all plugin instances created from the
    // e.g. $('input[type="range"]') elements.
    $('input[type="range"]').rangeslider('destroy');

    // Update all rangeslider instances for all
    // e.g. $('input[type="range"]') elements.
    // Usefull if you changed some attributes e.g. `min` or `max` etc.
    $('input[type="range"]').rangeslider('update', true);
</script>
```

Using jquery plugins in React is kind of an anti-pattern. Most of the time, people in the community will port old jquery libraries to React components. Here is a [React component for `RangeSlider`](https://github.com/whoisandy/react-rangeslider).

But you can still use the old jquery plugin.

You'll need to include the script tag for jquery and rangeslider in the `<head>` of your `index.html`.

Then, in your component, you'll need to add the range input:

```
<input
    type="range"
    min="10"                    // default 0
    max="1000"                  // default 100
    step="10"                   // default 1
    value="300"                 // default min + (max-min)/2
    data-orientation="vertical" // default horizontal
    ref={ref => this.range = ref}
>
```

And you'll need to initialize the plugin in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method:

```
componentDidMount() {
    $('input[type="range"]').rangeslider();
}
```

That should be all you need to get it working!

You could also look into using a [`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) for your input so that you could do something like:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.range.rangeslider();
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I did not realize it was a jquery plugin. I would highly recommend using the react-rangeslider library instead of the old jQuery plugin. As this answer suggests, jQuery and React aren't designed to work together.

Comment: One more question... If I do need to include the script tag in my html to load this library, what is the point of this library having an npm package?

Comment: @connected_user It's so you can do one or the other, but not both.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda So how would I import this using it's npm module?

Comment: The library that @ChaseDeAnda suggested has documentation about how it should be imported: https://github.com/whoisandy/react-rangeslider

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the library you are trying to import exports its code. If they have a module definition block, then you can try importing it using either `import` or `require` syntax in your module. Generally you can spot this by looking at the source for a code block that looks something like

```
if(typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define(["postal"], factory);
  } else if(typeof module === "object" && module.exports) {
    module.exports = factory(require("postal"));
  } else {
    root.myModule = factory(root.postal);
  }
```

If the library just adds functions/variables to the global namespace, then you can include the library with a `<script>` tag in the HTML, and call those functions directly like `window.someFunction` from inside your component.